# How does the assist system work?

Tags: smite

I have noticed that I am getting assists when I am near an enemy god that dies, despite not attacking the god.  Does the assist system merely work on distance as opposed to doing damage?  Do I not get an assist for hitting a god from distance?

Comment: Can you give an example? I suspect you have an ability (passive or active), or an item that is handing out an aura that affects either someone that participated in the kill, or the enemy that died.

Comment: afaik assists are proximity based.

Comment: @Ellesedil - I managed to get an assist with Raijin, using no abilities or items on a nearby enemy.  My guess is that you get an assist by being near the enemy OR damaging the enemy within the last few seconds of its death.  However, I'm not sure if a team mate has some form of item that also affects team mates?

Comment: Did you attack this enemy at all? I've gotten assists on kills quite some time after dying, for example. I don't think proximity matters. I've been right next to enemies when my teammates kill them without getting any sort of credit because I didn't have time to hit them with something. But, I'll rack up a lot of assists if I have an item with an aura. There are some nice magical power items that have auras. Double check your items to ensure you didn't have an item that had a passive aura affecting your allies. If you did, that's your answer.

Comment: @Ellesedil - No, this is when I don't attack the enemy.  I have noticed this in arena mostly, but also in joust.  I tried 1 game where I sold all my items and ran into a team fight without pressing anything.  I got killed, as did someone on the other team.  I got an assist.  Is there an item that a team mate can use to cause their team to also do proximity damage, perhaps?  BTW - I am playing on the Xbox One so not sure if there is a different assist system on the console version.

Comment: Was that with Raijin still? I have no qualms trying a similar experiment on PC.

Comment: @Ellesedil - Sun Wukong when I sold all my items.  It appears that if the god who died is in striking distance of your passive "ruler" you get an assist, regardless of whether you did any damage.  I am getting assists for gods who die shortly after ranged attacks (e.g. Vulcan's ult at max distance) - which is expected.  However, it's like "team fights" or "ganking" where you don't make any contact still gives you the assist.  Not sure if by design or a bug, but regardless the assists system seems to be over generous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To essentially piggy back on the comment section above.  In Smite (According to the [Smite Forums](http://forums.smitegame.com/showthread.php?15673-Assist-System) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Smite/comments/ygv2b/has_hirez_said_anything_about_the_assist_system/)) - You get Assist points for being in close proximity of the enemy god/gods that are being attacked and killed.  You can also receive Assist points for spectating in the region of a dying enemy god.  A LOT of people find this system broken and quite frustrating but Hi-Rez Studios has yet to address or patch this issue.  I hope this helped clear things up.